# Is there any difference between example_interfaces and std_msgs?

Tags: ros2, std-msgs

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from std_msgs.msg import String


class MinimalPublisher(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('minimal_publisher')
        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(String, 'topic', 10)
        timer_period = 0.5  # seconds
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
        self.i = 0

    def timer_callback(self):
        msg = String()
        msg.data = 'Hello World: %d' % self.i
        self.publisher_.publish(msg)
        self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "%s"' % msg.data)
        self.i += 1


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    minimal_publisher = MinimalPublisher()

    rclpy.spin(minimal_publisher)

    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    minimal_publisher.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Will there be any change if I use `example_interfaces.msg import String` instead of `from std_msgs.msg import String`?

Answer (score 0):

No, both messages will have the same data, you can check using the command:

`>> ros2 interface show <interface>`

And I think it is recommended to use the `example_interfaces/msg/String` instead of `std_msgs/msg/String`.

Comment: Yes, I got the same data. In the ROS official tutorial, they have used std_msgs, but a couple of tutorials I have seen have used example_interface. You are also saying example_interface is recommended. Wondering why that is!!!